# Brute Force algorithmmm

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the best value from a list of tuple satisfied the quantity doesn't exceed max_quantity.
Input:

```
list = [('a', 1, 19), ('b', 2, 19), ('c', 1, 49), ('d', 5, 79)]
```

The code:

```
for item in list:
  best_value = 0
  best_quant = 0
  set_value = sum(b[2] for b in item])
  set_quant = sum([b[1] for b in item])
  if set_value > best_value and set_quant <= max_quant:
     best_value = set_value 
     best_quant = set_quant
  print(best_value)
```

However, I keep running into type error occur in the line of set_value saying that 'int' object is not subcriptable. I don't get it because when I loop through the list it will be tuple and I try to index the tuple.

Comment: In the `set_value` line you are missing a `[` before the `b[2]`, or you can also remove the `]` at the end.

Comment: There's a typo here: `sum(b[2] for b in item])` The starting bracket is missing. Should be: `sum([b[2] for b in item])`

Comment: The `item` variable of the loop is each ``tuple. Then you do `b[2] for b in item`. So `b` gets the values of the tuple which some are ints, and you can't do `19[2]` in Python

Answer (score 2):

After fixing your bracket issue mentioned in the comments, and changing `list` => `_list` (don't use a builtin/type as a variable name), just get rid of the `for` loop and use list comp. on the outer `_list`:

```
_list = [('a', 1, 19), ('b', 2, 19), ('c', 1, 49), ('d', 5, 79)]

best_value = 0
best_quant = 0
set_value = sum([b[2] for b in _list])
set_quant = sum([b[1] for b in _list])
if set_value > best_value and set_quant <= max_quant:
   best_value = set_value 
   best_quant = set_quant
print(best_value)
```

You were already iterating in the list comp `b for b in...` but you can't get an element from the int that you already unpacked from the tuples.

Comment: i have tried get rid of the for loop but the best_value just doesn't update

Comment: Is that because the following condition is never True? `if set_value > best_value and set_quant <= max_quant` You can add a print statement inside that if statement to find out.

Comment: without the 'for' loop it just sum up all of the element in the list of tuple. What I'm trying to do is generate all possible combination of quantity and value . And if the quant <= max_quant, the best_value will be updated.

Comment: You can `import combinations from itertools`. Here is the documentation for combinations:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: there is no `max_quant` in the code only in the `if` so I guess that should be `best_quant`

Comment: the [max_quant] can be any variable that you can think of .